# Ethereum transaction wasn't processed in 240 seconds

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle-migration

I have deployed my private Blockchain via Ethereum Proof of Consortium. I have an intermittent issue on transaction. so far the only remedy is to restart the vm's but this issue happens again.

```
Transaction 0x6f34f71090b8ab768b53cb519aaaa4b7920f68fd72e466a7d02aaff96998c468 wasn't processed in 240 seconds.

_addTokenCustomized: function (tokenToEthaddress, tokenvalue, emailid) {
console.log(" Unlock Account :", web3.personal.unlockAccount(web3.eth.accounts[0],ethPassword));
    CoffeeCoin.deployed().then(function (contractInstance) {
      contractInstance.transfer(tokenToEthaddress, tokenvalue, { gas: 4500000, from: web3.eth.accounts[0] }).then(function (result) {
        if (result) {
        primus.send('red', "ccccccccc")
          console.log("token transfered")
            contractInstance.balanceOf(tokenToEthaddress).then(function (amount) {
              primus.send('red', "ccccccccc")
            document.getElementById('balance3').innerText = amount;
              var ts = (new Date).getTime();
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/addtoken',
                    type: 'POST',
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    data: JSON.stringify({
                        "SourceEmailID": emailid,
                        "TotalTokens": amount,
                        "TimeStamp": ts,
                    }),                                    
                    dataType: 'json',

                    success: function (res) {
                        console.log(res)
                    },
                    error: function (err) {
                        console.log('Error:', err)
                    }
                })
          });
        }
      }).catch(function (err) {
        // There was an error! Handle it.
        console.log("TransactionError: ", err);
      });
    })
}
```

Comment: did you setup at least block maker of some kind in your network ?

Comment: i donot know what is block maker,as i am using standard ethereum tempalte on azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

240 seconds timeout error during transaction was due to some Azure Network settings, native to "Ethereum Proof of Consortium" template , managed to fix this issue by spinning of 2 VM's on azure and deployed private blockchain from scratch and interconnected the nodes. In live production more than 20k instances of transaction and not a single instance of 240 seconds timeout error.